# Angular 4 printing html template

Tags: javascript, angular, printing

I'm trying to find a way to print a dynamic html view in angular 4.

this is what i have currently. Right now this will only print an element that is already rendered using the id assigned to it.

```
let printContents, popupWin;
   printContents = document.getElementById(this.printElementId).innerHTML;
   console.log(printContents);

   popupWin = window;

   //popupWin.resizeTo(window.outerWidth, window.outerHeight);
   popupWin = popupWin.open('', `_blank', 'top=0,left=0,width=${window.outerWidth},height=${window.outerHeight}`);

   popupWin.document.open();
   popupWin.document.write(`
      <html>
          <head>
              <title>${this.printTitle}</title>
              <style></style>
          </head>
          <body onload="window.print();window.close()">
            ${printContents}
          </body>
      </html>`
   );}
```

Is there an easy solution for this?

Comment: Haven't tried it. But Googling led me to this:  "generating a print layout of web page in angular 2" https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/create-print-component-angular2-which-user-defined-html-rajesh-g (angular 2 & 4 are going to be similar beasts)

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd do it this way. The easiest way would be to use css and media queries specifically for printing. At least that's what I would do instead regenerating/copy/pasting html around.

Comment: the print screen is a completely different look, but some of the content within the screen is dependent on data that i retrieve from an api. The content will be different for each user who clicks the print button.